# How to get jar installation or runtime path in j2me/lwuit?

Tags: jar, java-me, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I have an application built on j2me/lwuit to work on Nokia s40 phone.

I want to know the path where the application runs from. Do we have a way to get the path? Can anybody help me on this?

Say, for an E.g I have the application in both Games and Extras folder, when I run the application from Games it should return the path of Games and vice versa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, from j2me application you can not get that information